# stuck calling oracle procedure multiple times

Tags: c#, oracle, plsql

any way I can speed this up.  I have to call the stored procedure each time to get its latest value from oracle and update.  This is my last bottleneck, as it can be called thousands of times.   I converted my other inserts into array binding bulk inserts.

c# call oracle

```
for (int i = 0; i < r.receiptkey.Count(); i++)
{       
  ld.receiptlinenumber.Add(AsnGetNextAvailableReceiptLineNumber(r.receiptkey[i]));
}
```

c# oracle

```
 public string AsnGetNextAvailableReceiptLineNumber(string myReceiptKey)
    {
        using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand())
        {
            OracleConnection conn;
            conn = new OracleConnection(ConnectionStringOracle);
            cmd.CommandText = "bpPack.GetNextReceiptLineNumber";
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Connection = conn;

            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("iReceiptKey", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 10));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("oRetValue", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 5)).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            cmd.Parameters["iReceiptKey"].Value = myReceiptKey;
            conn.Open();
            try
            {
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception e9)
            {
                return "Error" + e9.Message;
            }
            return cmd.Parameters["oRetValue"].Value.ToString();
        }
    }
```

the plsql

```
  PROCEDURE GetNextReceiptLineNumber(
   iReceiptKey IN VARCHAR2,
   oRetValue OUT VARCHAR2)
  IS
    xreceiptlinenumber VARCHAR2 (5);
    xreceiptlinecount  NUMBER (10);
  BEGIN
     xreceiptlinenumber :='';
     xreceiptlinecount  := 0;
     SELECT MAX (receiptlinenumber)
    INTO xreceiptlinenumber
     FROM receiptdetail
    WHERE receiptkey        = iReceiptKey;
   IF (xreceiptlinenumber IS NULL) THEN
    xreceiptlinecount    := 0;
  ELSE
    xreceiptlinecount := TO_NUMBER (LTRIM (xreceiptlinenumber, '0'));
  END IF;
  xreceiptlinecount := xreceiptlinecount + 1;
  oRetValue         := LPAD (xreceiptlinecount, 5, '0');
  END GetNextReceiptLineNumber;
```

Comment: Look like that procedure can be rewritten as a single SELECT query. Then you may be able to run it once for many values at the same time (especially if those receiptKeys are already stored in the database somewhere).

Answer (score 0):

Do not connect on each procedure call - separate connection code and your procedure call code.

---

Your procedure can get into situation of getting duplicates (imagine what happens if two session call it with the same key at the same time - use sequences instead of max if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can elaborate the results retrieved by the following query in your C# code.

```
SELECT receiptkey, LPAD (nvl((to_number(MAX(receiptlinenumber))+1),'0'), 5, '0') as NextReceiptLineNumber
FROM receiptdetail
group by receiptkey
```